# Run php -S command in docker container (oneoff)

Tags: php, docker

I have a simple php app i want to serve local in a Docker container with the specific PHP version (5.6), I have the latest PHP version on my local machine.

I can't get it to work.

my try:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 --rm --name server-php-56 -v "$PWD":/app -w /app/public php:5.6 php -S localhost:8000
```

i got this output:

```
PHP 5.6.32 Development Server started at Mon Nov 20 14:09:29 2017
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /app/public

Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

looks great:
but is not working when i hit the http://localhost:8000

it is not working ...

```
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arhhh ... damn, now I got it to work ..

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 --rm --name server-php-56 -v "$PWD":/app -w /app/public php:5.6 php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I had to run the server on 0.0.0.0:8000